# Representation theory of $\mathbb{Z}_k$ and complex roots of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, representation-theory

Is there a natural relationship between the (characters?) of irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_k$ and the $k$ complex-roots of unity?

Can they be like thought of as characters of its 1-dimensional irreducible representations?

If something like this holds what would be the analogous statement for general groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by $\mathbb Z_k$ you mean $\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z$, the cyclic group of order $k$.  (Most number theorists don't like this notation.)  In this case $\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to the group of $k$-th roots of unity under multpilication.  Because it is abelian, all irreducible representations are 1-dimensional, i.e., linear characters.

For finite abelian groups, there is a non-canonical (meaning one needs to make an arbitrary choice) isomorphism between the group and its group of characters (you can multiply characters).  For finite non-abelian groups, the irreducible representations (or characters) do not form a group, but there is a (again non-canonical) bijection between the conjugacy classes of the group and its irreducible representations.

**Edit:** To be more explicit, let $\zeta$ be a (not necessarily primitive) $k$-th root of 1 in $\mathbb C$, i.e., $\zeta = e^{2\pi i j/k}$ for some $j = 0, 1, \ldots, k-1$.  Now consider the map $\alpha_\zeta(a) = \zeta^a$ for $a \in \mathbb Z/k \mathbb Z$.  This is an irreducible character, and one gets all of them this way.  So the association $\zeta \mapsto \alpha_\zeta$ defines an isomorphism of the $k$-th roots of unity with the character group of $\mathbb Z/k \mathbb Z$.

One can do something similar for finite abelian groups, but it requires a choice of basis (it's perhaps not obvious, but the above isomorphism used the basis $1$ for $\mathbb Z/k \mathbb Z$.)  E.g., take the basis $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ for $G =\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$.  Now let $\zeta_m$ and $\zeta_n$ be $m$ and $n$-th roots of unity.  We can define an irreducible character of $G$ by sending $(1,0)$ to $\zeta_m$ and $(0,1)$ to $\zeta_n$, and all characters arise this way.  Precisely, the character is given by $(a, b) \mapsto \zeta_m^a \zeta_n^b$.  So the irreducible characters correspond to pairs of $m$ and $n$-th roots of unity.  This correspondence works for finite abelian groups, which are all isomorphic to a product $\mathbb Z/k_1 \mathbb Z \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z/k_n \mathbb Z$, but not for nonabelian groups.

Comment: But how many irreducible representations are there of Z_k and are they somehow related/parametrized by the k complex roots of unity? Some mapping which can then later be generalized to other groups?

Comment: I added an explicit parameterization and some comments.  Does this clarify things?

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a typo about what is $\xi$? I would have thought that there are $k$ different choices of $\xi$ parametrized as $\xi_m = e^{\frac{2\pi i m }{k}}$ for $0\leq m \leq (k-1)$. Then for every choice of $m$ you have a map, $\alpha_m : \mathbb{Z}_k \rightarrow S^1$ as, $\alpha_m (p) = \xi_m^p$. So if these $\alpha_m$s are called ``irreducible characters" for $\mathbb{Z}_k$ then there are $k$ such irreducible characters - one for each $m$. Now this set of $\{\alpha_m\}$ forms a group on its own under pointwise multiplication on the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_k$.

Comment: But here we have an extra special feature that is group $\{\alpha_m\}$ (the Pontryagin dual?) is also canonically isomorphic to the original group $\mathbb{Z}_k$ via the map, $\alpha_m \rightarrow \xi_m$ - right?

Comment: Now lets say you introduce $\phi_n = e^{\frac{2 \pi i n }{p} }$ as the $p$ $p^{th}$ roots of unity one for each $1\leq n \leq (p-1)$. And the corresponding $pk$ number of characters of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_k$ are given by the map $\alpha_{(m,n)} (i,j) \rightarrow \xi_m^i \xi_n^j$ - right? And again this set of maps $\{ \alpha_{(m,n)} \}$ form the Pontryagin dual of the group $\mathbb{Z}_k \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ - right?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo.  I fixed it.  For your other questions yes, except the isomorphism is explicit but not canonical (I had to fix presentations of both group).  This is easier to see if you think about an abstract finite cyclic group.  Which generator do you send to which root of unity?  There are many that will give you isomorphisms with the dual.  (By the way, Pontryagin duality is a further generalization of this phenomenon).

Comment: Thanks! Why are these maps $\alpha_m$ (in my notation) called "irreducible characters"? Whats the connection to representation theory here? Characters are trace functions - whats that here.. [...I guess you mean by non-canonical-ness that there is a $k!$ multiplicy of possibilities about the isomorphism map between the dual group of $\{\alpha_m\}$ and the group $\mathbb{Z}_k$ - right?..]

Comment: By irreducible character, I mean the character of an irreducible representation (though I didn't say irreducible everywhere I meant it).  The sum of 2 characters is also a (reducible) character, which is the trace of the direct sum of the two corresponding representations.

Comment: This $\alpha_m$ is a character of which representation?

Comment: In this case, since the group is abelian, all irreducible representations are 1-dimensional, i.e., homomorphisms into $\mathbb C^\times$, so these are the exact same thing as the irreducible characters.

Comment: Let me make my question precise. A 1-dimn representation of $\mathbb{Z}_k$ would be a homomorphism map $\rho : \mathbb{Z}_k \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C})$ . Are you saying that there are exactly $k$ such maps each corresponding to multiplication by some root of unity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20501/discussion-between-kimball-and-user6818).